# With Codname one how can I add mutilple attachements to an email

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I'm working on an app that I'd like to have the functionality of attaching multiple images to an email. I'm using the Message class.
I got it working fine with a single attachment, using the setAttachment() function.

However when I attempted to attach multiple emails I hit a wall.
Looking at the comments in the source It seems like the function getAttachments() should allow adding multiple attachment.
But the map doesn't seem to be ready anywhere else in the Message class.
I could upload all the images to a server and just link them in the email, but I was hoping to have it self contained if possible.
Another option would be to zip all the images into a file and attach that. But it seems we can only zip to tar balls which isn't really that useful for most end users.

The best solution is multiple attachements, is it possible with Message? 
Do I have to subclass?

Here is what I'm attempting in code:

```
Message message = new Message("" + currentReport.getField("Title") + "\n\n" + currentReport.getField("Comment"));
        java.util.List<ReportImage> images = currentReport.getField("Images");
        Map<String,String> attachements = message.getAttachments();
        for(ReportImage img: images){
            if (img != null && img.getField("Path") != null) {
                String path = img.getField("Path");
                attachements.put(path, path.toLowerCase().endsWith("png") ? Message.MIME_IMAGE_PNG : Message.MIME_IMAGE_JPG);
            }
        }
        String[] sendTo = {""};
        Message.sendMessage(sendTo, "Error Report " + sdf.format(new Date()), message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote should work but you should notice that this should be a path to a file using [FileSystemStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html) and not to the [Storage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html) class.

This was unclear in the docs and I clarified it a bit for the next documentation update.